# I want to remove / using regexp in kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to remove / using regexp in kibana. is this possible?
i already tried a few options,

```
Label:"/"
Label:"/\"
Label:"*/\*"
```

those are the options i tried.
it is for a specific dashboard so it must not disappear throughout the whole application.

Comment: try  using Label:"\/"

Comment: that does not work

Comment: Check this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160264/2251411