# Kibana search with regular expression not working

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am trying to find some logs in Kibana by using Regular Expressions. I am aware that Kibana doesn't support the "classical" RegEx, but rather Lucene Query Syntax. I have read through the documentation of it (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) and imo my queries should work, but they don't.

Here is an example log entry that I want to target with my query:

> Timings are: sync started at 2019-02-12 19:15:09.402; accounts
>   downloaded:+760ms/760ms; accounts data downloaded:+1221ms/1981ms;
>   categorization pushed:+0ms/1981ms; categorization
>   started:+131ms/2112ms; categorization completed:+123ms/2235ms; in
>   total:2235ms.

What I want to find in the end is all such log entries where the time of "categorization started" exceeds a certain threshold. However my queries fail already while just trying to approach the final query.

I get results when I query:

```
message:"/categorization started/"
```

But already when i modify it to:

```
message:/categorization started/
```

i get nothing. Any of the following attemps also give nothing:

```
 message:/categorization\sstarted/
 message:/.*categorization\sstarted.*/
 message:/.*categorization.*started.*/
```

At this point I'm already lost - why do all these queries not match anything?

In my mind, the final query that should get what I want should be as follows (finding all entries where categorization started time was 10,000ms or more):

```
message:/.*categorization started:\+<10000-99999>ms.*/
```

It goes without saying that this of course also returns nothing, which doesn't surprise me when the above queries already fail.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: There must be no `/` at the start and end. And the `+` must be double escaped. `".*categorization started:\\+<10000-99999>ms\\.*"`. Make sure to set `"flags":"ALL"`.

Comment: maybe there is a misunderstanding. I am using kibana website to enter the query. There it explains that regexp must be caputred in leading and trailing slash. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

Comment: Not sure but probably the string you match against is whitespace tokenized. See [this article](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/regex-search-in-kibana/97436).

Comment: Your link, and I'm guessing also you, jumped right past the part of the documentation that explains this: "...Elasticsearch will apply the regexp *to the terms produced by the tokenizer for that field*, and not to the original text of the field."

Comment: Thank you guys for making me aware of this. I have not set up the elastic search for our app myself, so I guess I will have to talk back with DevOps to find out how our fields are handled

Comment: I don't believe this is handled very well with Lucene. I found an alternate approach to do this in Kibana. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160264/2251411

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use

```
message:*categorization started*
```